# How do I place a progress bar in AndEngine?

Tags: andengine

I am developing game using AndEngine. I need to place a progress bar in my game to denote time remaining in the game. Is there a built-in method for doing this in AndEngine? My searches only turned up results for Android, not for AndEngine.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply need to have a progress bar alongside your game you can use the [LayoutGameActivity](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/ui/activity/LayoutGameActivity.java) which was [added for that purpose](http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/combining-andengine-with-regular-widgets-t699.html#p3505). `LayoutGameActivity` allows you to place the andEngine View into a standard Android layout which is loaded from XML, rather than using its default layout. As mentioned in the article, this is accomplished by overriding `getLayoutID()` and `getRenderSurfaceViewID()` in your game `LayoutGameActivity` class.

For example:

```
@Override
protected int getLayoutID() {
        return R.layout.xmllayoutexample;
}

@Override
protected int getRenderSurfaceViewID() {
        return R.id.xmllayoutexample_rendersurfaceview;
}
```

Code fragment from the linked [forum post](http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/combining-andengine-with-regular-widgets-t699.html#p3505).

Answer (score 2):

You could also just vary the width of a simple rectangle over time, or if you want to have it nicer, stitch together a couple of sprites.